# BGP: Route congestion

Tags: bgp, congestion

Using a BGP Multihoming design, is it possible redirect or modify any metric to determinate destination?

Example: I detected that the most of users are having problem to access a webserver: high latency, loss packet. Being LINK A the preferential path, is there any way to add weight or modify any thing which change the preferential path to LINK B, only that destination?

[image: A simple example of my network]

Huawei NE20: Quite simply this load sharing configuration.

```
bgp 42
 router-id 172.16.01
 peer 10.10.10.5 as-number 26
 peer 10.10.10.5 connect-interface GigabitEthernet0/3/1
 peer 10.9.5.36 as-number 16
 peer 10.9.5.36 connect-interface GigabitEthernet0/3/3

 #
 ipv4-family unicast
  undo synchronization
  network 192.168.0.0 255.255.240.0
  network 192.168.128.0 255.255.248.0  
  peer 10.10.10.5 enable
  peer 10.10.10.5 route-policy LINKA export
  peer 10.9.5.36 enable
  peer 10.9.5.36 route-policy LINKB export  

route-policy LINKB permit node 10
 if-match ip-prefix PREFIX-1
#
route-policy LINKB permit node 20
 if-match ip-prefix PREFIX-2
#
route-policy LINKA permit node 10
 if-match ip-prefix PREFIX-1
#
route-policy LINKA permit node 20
 if-match ip-prefix PREFIX-2
#
ip ip-prefix PREFIX-1 index 10 permit 192.168.128.0 22
ip ip-prefix PREFIX-2 index 10 permit 192.168.0.0 21
```

*Note: Omitting the real ip address*

Comment: The answer is definitely maybe.  We need to know more about your network- please update your question with your router configurations and a simple diagram.  Also note that while it's possible to change the outbound path, you have only limited control over the inbound path.

Comment: You do not have any real way to change how the ISPs in the path route traffic. You can change where the traffic exits your network.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In theory, the answer is yes, but based on your diagram and description, the practical answer is **NO**.

The problem is you can control your outbound traffic, but you have little control over your inbound traffic.  For a webserver, traffic loads are very asymmetrical, and the vast amount of traffic is inbound.

You can control inbound traffic only to the point the your upstream AS's agree to do so. If they don't want to follow your signalling, there's not much you can do.  Since you have two different ISP's they may not cooperate with each other.

Furthermore, ISPs limit the length of prefixes they allow you to advertise, usually a maximum of /24.  So even if you advertised a more specific route for your webserver out of ISP B, they wouldn't accept it because they limit your prefix advertisements to /24.

Finally, you need to be very careful when programatically changing routing as a result of traffic loads.  You can create a lot of instability in your network.  Imagine link A is the preferred path, but it has high latency due to traffic loads.  So you move some traffic to B.  Now Link A's latency goes down because there's less traffic on the link.  So your router switches traffic back to A.  And the latency increases again.  So it switches again....etc.

Answer (score 1):

Outbound yes you can set different BGP attributes such as local preference or weight for the routes received from each connection.

Inbound you are at the mercy of the upstream but you can use AS prepending to "fail over" traffic to prefer one session over the other.